# AngularJS: First button in form fires on enter button press even though it is not a submit button

Tags: angularjs, angular-meteor, getuikit

If I press the enter button after editing `input_a`, `processInputA()` is called. The `submit()` function is omitted.

This does not happen for `input_b`: It works as expected even though it is similar to `input_a`. The `submit()` function is called as expected.

**How can I prevent the button after `input_a` from firing?**

```
<form class="uk-form" ng-submit="submit()">
  <div class="uk-form-row">
    <input type="text"
           name="input_a"
           ng-model="buffer.inputA" ng-change="reportInputATyped()"
           class="uk-width-3-10 uk-form-small">
    <button ng-cloak ng-show="inputADirty" class="uk-button uk-button-small" ng-click="processInputA()">Apply</button>
    /
    <input type="text"
           name="input_b"
           ng-model="buffer.inputB" ng-change="reportInputBTyped()"
           class="uk-width-6-10 uk-form-small">
    <button ng-cloak ng-show="inputBDirty" class="uk-button uk-button-small" ng-click="processInputB()">Apply</button>
  </div>
  // ...further inputs...
</form>
```

AngularJS: http://angular-meteor.com

Styles: http://getuikit.com

Comment: Can you create a demo? It is obvious why enter fires submit, but the second should behave the same. Probably some of your code which you don't show interacts with it preventing it in case of the second input.

Comment: It _does not_ fire submit when I press it in the first input: It fires the click handler `processInputA()`. (but it _should_ fire submit instead).

Comment: It is just local code. No idea how I could create a demo...

Comment: set the type of the buttons to "button".

Comment: Thanks rob, that solved it. Now enter solely fires submit. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<button>` elements seem to be of default type `submit` if rendered through Chrome. Not what I expected intuitively.

The W4Schools.com article states the tip:

> Always specify the type attribute for the  element. Different browsers may use different default types for the  element.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Version that works if processed by Chrome:

```
<form class="uk-form" ng-submit="submit()">
  <div class="uk-form-row">
    <input type="text"
           name="input_a"
           ng-model="buffer.inputA" ng-change="reportInputATyped()"
           class="uk-width-3-10 uk-form-small">
    <button type="button" ng-cloak ng-show="inputADirty" class="uk-button uk-button-small" ng-click="processInputA()">Apply</button>
    /
    <input type="text"
           name="input_b"
           ng-model="buffer.inputB" ng-change="reportInputBTyped()"
           class="uk-width-6-10 uk-form-small">
    <button type="button" ng-cloak ng-show="inputBDirty" class="uk-button uk-button-small" ng-click="processInputB()">Apply</button>
  </div>
  // ...further inputs...
</form>
```